# Qt charts, series not displayed

Tags: c++, qt, charts, qt5

I struggle to understand how data is updated with Qt Charts.

I implemented all basics (series, chart, chartview) and add the data to the series.
However the shown curve contains only values of 0.

```
widgetHistogramm::widgetHistogramm(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent)
{
    // create line Series for the data
    series = new QLineSeries();
    // create Chart Object (QWidget)
    chart = new QChart();
    chart->legend()->hide();
    chart->addSeries(series);
    chart->createDefaultAxes();
    chart->setTitle("Histogramm");


    xAxis = new QtCharts::QValueAxis;
    yAxis = new QtCharts::QValueAxis;
    chart->setAxisX(xAxis);
    chart->setAxisY(yAxis);

    // create a view inside the Chart
    chartView = new QChartView(chart, this);

    // Create a layout and add Chart
    QGridLayout *layout = new QGridLayout(this);
    layout->addWidget(chartView);
}

widgetHistogramm::~widgetHistogramm()
{

}


void widgetHistogramm::setData(const std::vector<int> data)
{
    auto max = *max_element(std::begin(data), std::end(data));

    chart->axisX()->setRange(0, data.size());
    chart->axisY()->setRange(0, max);

    series->clear();
    for(std::vector<int>::size_type i = 0; i != data.size(); i++) {
        series->append(i, data[i]);
    }    
    chart->update();
}
```

Additionally I would like to know when data is shown. On every `append` or only on `update`?

Comment: With a vector containing 256 values. The range 5-15 contains values in a gaussian curve. All other values or 0.

Comment: It works afer removing the additional xAxis and yAxis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is caused by `chart->setAxisX()` and `chart->setAxisY()`, you must pass the series:

```
chart->setAxisX(xAxis, series);
chart->setAxisY(yAxis, series);
```

Or simply delete those lines because when calling `createDefaultAxes()` you are creating axes.

On the other hand, you should not call `update()`, every time you add or delete an element of the series, this will notify the view by internally calling `update().`

Comment: Ok. But how can I disable the update. Once I accidentally have passed a vector with millions of entrys and the app froze.

Comment: see https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qxyseries.html#append-2, You can pass all the data at once.

Comment: can I call `createDefaultAxes()` every time I have update my `series` object?